# How to see endpoint name from HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Let's say I have a razor page application, and there is a razor page "Product.cshtml", how can I see "Product.cshtml" string in the HttpContext object (assuming I can access the HttpContext object in the middleware before endpoint middleware as the code below shows)? I tried to use `EndpointHttpContextExtensions.GetEndpoint(HttpContext)` extension method, still couldn't find anything that might contain "Product.cshtml".

```
// startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseMiddleware<GetEndPointMiddleWare>();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
      endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   });
}

public class GetEndPointMiddleWare
{
   private RequestDelegate next;
   public QueryStringMiddleWare(RequestDelegate nextDelegate) {
      next = nextDelegate;
   }
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
      ...
      await next(context);
      // I want to print "Product.cshtml" here
      // var endpoint = EndpointHttpContextExtensions.GetEndpoint(context); // <---- didn't find any property that has the string I want          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the page is within the [endpoint metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpoint.metadata?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as part of a [`PageActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageactiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) object, so that could be accessed and parsed. An example of middleware that inspects the page path:

```
// Startup.cs -> Configure()

app.UseRouting();

app.Use(next => context =>
{
    var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
    if (endpoint is null)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    if (endpoint.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(i => i is PageActionDescriptor) is PageActionDescriptor pageDescriptor)
    {
        string pagePath = pageDescriptor.RelativePath;
        Console.WriteLine($"Page path: {pagePath}"); // '/Pages/Product.cshtml'
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

(Adapted from [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-endpoint-definition))

Comment: `.GetEndpoint()` not found .net 6.0