# How to get IP4 Address from HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried using all three of these techniques to lookup what IP is calling my controller's method.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

All of these yield IPV6 addresses.  `IPAddress.MapToIPv4()` yields an incorrect V4 address.

How do I get IPV4 addresses?

Note: this link, [Problem Converting ipv6 to ipv4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043769/125981), shows that a V6 can't be converted to a V4.  I'm looking to just use V4 entirely.

Comment: Use the endpoint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380474/how-to-see-endpoint-name-from-httpcontext

Comment: Why do you assume there is an IPv4 address to begin with? If all network devices between client and server are configured for IPv6, the connection will be made using IPv6 addresses. By now most computers and smartphones support IPv6. While home and business routers may still use IPv4 I'd expect mobile providers to use IPv6 in their networks.

Comment: The fact `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` contains an IPv6 address means the client itself connected using IPv6 *and* that the connection went through NAT or a load balancer that put the original address in that header.

Comment: Is there is specific reason why you are capturing the I.P addresses? Are you just storing them in a DB or are they to be used for other purposes like getting geo location etc?